# Applescript Mail Attachment Not Sending

Tags: applescript, email-attachments

The following Applescript sends an email successfully but does not attach the wav file.  Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you.

```
    tell application "Mail"

    set theSubject to "Voicemail"
    set theContent to read (the POSIX path of "/private/tmp/voice.tgCrnv/BODY.txt")
    set theAddress to "me@example1.com"
    set theSender to "me@example2.com"
    set theAttachmentFile to (POSIX file "/private/tmp/voice.tgCrnv/msg_1bb3b4f2-c6b1-4012-89c0-a19177cc6ca2.wav") as string

    set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, visible:false, sender:theSender}

    tell msg to make new to recipient at end of every to recipient with properties {address:theAddress}
    tell msg to make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachmentFile as alias}

    send msg
end tell
```

Comment: Try declaring `visible:true` in the properties of your `outgoing message` when you first declare it, i.e. `set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, visible:true, sender:theSender}`

Comment: I just tried it with a wave file At 5 MB.. And it worked.  Then I tried with a wave file at 60 MB and it did not work.  My guess is the file size is just too large to send via email.  You may need to convert the wave file to MP3 format (Which is considerably smaller) First, Then send the MP3 instead

Comment: @CJK - thanks, but that didn't help

Comment: It's not working for me now either.. It works With a wave file at 0 kB.. Hang tight guys, I'll figure out a solution LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work for me

```
set theSubject to "Voicemail"
set theContent to read "/private/tmp/voice.tgCrnv/BODY.txt"
set theAddress to "me@example1.com"
set theSender to "me@example2.com"
set theAttachmentFile to "/private/tmp/voice.tgCrnv/msg_1bb3b4f2-c6b1-4012-89c0-a19177cc6ca2.wav" as POSIX file as alias

tell application "Mail"
    set msg to make new outgoing message with properties ¬
        {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, visible:false, sender:theSender}
    tell msg
        make new to recipient at end of every to recipient with properties {address:theAddress}
        make new attachment at end of last character of content with properties ¬
            {file name:theAttachmentFile}
    end tell
    delay 1
    send msg
end tell
```

Comment: I see the mild syntactical difference in the way we've sent our commands to the message and set up the attachment, but I don't see why one worked and the other didn't.  Programmatically, you and I created identical scripts, with the exception of the `delay`.  Anyway, well done.  You deserve a +1 for that.

Comment: @CJK actually I would've worded the scripting slightly different but I was trying to beat you to the punch LOL

Comment: Well down, delay is important

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly adjusted your script that I believe will work if you first try it as it is before making any edits of your own to suit your own coding style (obviously, fill in the appropriate email addresses).

The significant functional changes are setting `visible` to `true` when declaring a new `outgoing message`; and targetting the `content` of the `outgoing message` in order to attach the file.

The variable declarations I moved to outwith the `tell application` block just for good coding practice (there's no need to tell *Mail* to set those variables, so don't).

And, finally, I reformatted the text of the code to what I'm more accustomed to for improved readability.

```
    set theSubject to "Voicemail"
    set theContent to read "/private/tmp/voice.tgCrnv/BODY.txt"
    set theAddress to "me@example1.com"
    set theSender to "me@example2.com"
    set theAttachmentFile to POSIX file "/private/tmp/voice.tgCrnv/msg_1bb3b4f2-c6b1-4012-89c0-a19177cc6ca2.wav" as alias

    tell application "Mail" to tell (make new outgoing message with properties ¬
        {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, visible:true, sender:theSender})

        make new to recipient at end of to recipients ¬
            with properties {address:theAddress}

        tell its content to make new attachment at after the last paragraph ¬
            with properties {file name:theAttachmentFile}

        send
    end tell
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your edited script in Script Editor.  Again, it sent the email correctly, just without the attachment.  Script Editor shows all of the correct things in the Events pane.

Comment: Ahh... I guess my system is slightly quicker than yours at accessing and attaching a file.  My `jpg` was a few hundred kilobytes, so I was convinced it would suffice for your needs.  Oh well, I'm glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: larger files need longer delays. 10mb - I know, too huge, but ... - needed upward of 8 second delay.

Comment: Update: In Mojave sending attachments, for me at least, was intermittent and unreliable, even with quite a long delay. But, purely by accident, I found that if the mail app is activated it all works. Just add an activate command immediately after 'tell ...'